# Reading Binary files in C++ 2

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I had just started with binary files. I tried out a simple programme:

```
class student
{
    int rno;
    char sname[20];
    public:
    void input();
    void output();
};

void main() 
{
    clrscr();
    student s;
    char reply;
    fstream fil;

    fil.open("stu.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
    do
    {
        s.input();
        fil.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        cout<<"more (Y/N)\n";
        cin>>reply;
    }
    while(toupper(reply)=='Y');
    fil.close();
}

 void  student::input()
 {
 cout<<"enter the roll\n";
 cin>>rno;
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"enter the name\n";
 gets(sname);
 cout<<endl;
 }

 void  student::output()  
 { 
 cout<<" the roll\n";
 cout<<rno;
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"the name\n";
 puts(sname);
 cout<<endl;
```

But when i read this (say i have added 3 students) only last student's details are shown. why?
Reading code:

```
  #include<fstream.h>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<ctype.h>

  class student
  {
  int rno;
  char sname[20];
  public:
  void input();
  void output();
  };

  void main()
  {
  clrscr();
  student s;
  fstream fil;
  fil.open("stu.dat",ios::binary|ios::in);

  while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)));
  {
  s.output();
  getch();
  }
  fil.close();  
  }  

  void  student::input()
  {
  cout<<"enter the roll\n";
  cin>>rno;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"enter the name\n";
  gets(sname);
  cout<<endl;
  }

  void  student::output()
  {
  cout<<" the roll\n";
  cout<<rno;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"the name\n";
  puts(sname);
  cout<<endl;
  }
```

But when i read this (say i have added 3 students) only last student's details are shown. why?

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Since you don't show the reading code who can say? You seem to be assuming that the fault is in the writing code, but it looks more or less OK to me.

Comment: It is NOT safe to dump an object out to a file as binary and read it back in. You must use a function to read/write the fields individually.

Comment: @NeilKirk It is safe under some limited circumstances, Can't recall right now if those circumstances cover the OP's class or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest letting the student write itself to file

```
void student::Write( fstream & fil )
{
  fil.write((char*)&rno,sizeof( rno ));
  fil.write((char*)&sname,20);
}
```

This way, if your class attributes change you do not need to rewrite anything but the student implementation code.

Comment: But can you tell me why i am getting an error?  I also tried combining  the two programs in one but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Try the change, your code will be much better, and the 'error' may have gone.  There is no point in just staring at code, spend the time to improve it until you either fix the problem or notice what is causing it because your code is so much cleaner.  Right now your code is so messy, it is hard to know what is happening.